# Create a file containing php execution result

Tags: php, android, jackson

I have a php file that selects all rows in a table, i want to store result content in a file in www/ directory, like that i can parse that name.json file and display its content in Android using jackson library.
Here is my php file:

```
<?php header('Content-type: application/json');

/*
 * Following code will list all the surveys
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all surveys from surveys table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM surveys") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // surveys node
    $response["surveys"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $survey = array();
        $survey["id_survey"] = $row["id_survey"];
        $survey["question_survey"] = $row["question_survey"];
        $survey["answer_yes"] = $row["answer_yes"];
        $survey["answer_no"] = $row["answer_no"];




        // push single survey into final response array
        array_push($response["surveys"], $survey);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no surveys found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No surveys found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

So: php file => execution => storing result in file => parse that file and display it in Android.

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Are you trying to change the data path for academic reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write JSON down to file, just add:

```
file_put_contents( "filename.json", json_encode($response) );
```

next to or instead of your `echo`;

Comment: I did that to execute php file from android: `String url = "http://192.168.1.4/android_connect/get_all_surveys.php";
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

     try {
       client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
     } catch(IOException e) {
       //do something here
     }` but nothing happens, the file is empty.

Comment: I though about executing the php file, the file will put result in filename.json file, then from that fiile i can parse json data. But...

Comment: Do you understand your code? If file is empty then `$response` had to be empty - there's no magic here - you cannot write something out of nothing. If `echo json_decode()` displays the content, then `file_put_contents()` have to write it, unless you got no permission to write or look for file at wrong location

Comment: $reponse is NOT empty, when i execute the file in browser and echo $response i have a well json format. That's why I asked.

Comment: and here is what it gives: `{"surveys":[{"id_survey":"1","question_survey":"Are you happy with the actual government?","answer_yes":"50","answer_no":"20"}],"success":1}` So it's not empty and outputs a well json format.

Comment: `file_put_contents()` is PHP5 - are you on older version? If not, try using some absolute path to ensure you look for the right file at right place. Aside of that, if you access `http://192.168.1.4/android_connect/get_all_surveys.php` and this script writes json to file and then you want to access that file then it basically makes little sense - why processing `echo`-ed output is wrong? If your data changes rarely then ok, cache, but otherwise?

Comment: When executing php file from browser it supposed to write the content on filename.json file. but filename.json is empty so it does not succeed to write on it.

Comment: try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and execute from browser. Remove that file first to ensure it is really created and you are not facing permission conflict somehow. You can try `file_put_contents('filename', 'test');` to check too. It simply have to work

Comment: So i did what you said, i have that error: `SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\tunisian_surveys\get_all_surveys.php on line 9
` line 9 is : `$response = array();` That's really strange.

Comment: you lack closing `}` in the else block. Also I'd remove `?>` - it is useless here

Comment: Here is the correct one, there is no error, but file is not created: http://pastebin.com/Fnh0NhG9

Comment: sure it is not created - you write that file only if you got no data :) Else move `file_put_contents()` outside `if/else` block completely, or add another `file_put_contents()` after first `echo` (that one in `if` block.

Comment: I tried it early and it did not work. I'll try it another time JUST NOW.

Comment: I accept your answer, you're the best. And how did i not noticed that ? How I did not noticed that it's in the unsuccessful IF bloc? I guess that I'm not for developing! F***k !!!!!! Thank you dude you're always here :)

Comment: Now I'm beginning the execution php file from Android... Good luck for me poor dev :(.

Comment: Practice will make you better, so do not worry :)

Comment: Can you please just help me in that final step? I used that java code to execute the php file `String url = "http://192.168.1.4/android_connect/get_all_surveys.php";
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         try {
           client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
           Log.d("EXECUTED",client.execute(new HttpGet(url)).toString());
         } catch(IOException e) {
          
         }`, I've used a ProgressDialog, however, the file is not created, so the php file is not executed. Is there something wrong with that code? (I open a new topic?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453635/php-file-in-server-not-executed-from-android-client Thank you for helping