# PHP file in server not executed from android client

Tags: android

I'm returning to you another time because i'm simply blocked. I want to execute a php file stored in server, for that, i used that code:

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
           // Network operation
            String url = "http://192.168.1.4/android_connect/get_all_surveys.php";
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {

              client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
              Log.d("EXECUTED",client.execute(new HttpGet(url)).toString());
            } catch(IOException e) {
              Log.d("EXCEPTION EXECUTION",e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I want to indicate that that Log `Log.d("EXECUTED",client.execute(new HttpGet(url)).toString());` is displayed so there is surely something wrong on that line `client.execute(new HttpGet(url));` executing a php script is not simply a http get request?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks ok. But you are executing your GET request twice for no real reason (also there's not "executing PHP script" - you are doing just GET request. What action it would trigger on server is another story).

Replace this code:

```
client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
Log.d("EXECUTED",client.execute(new HttpGet(url)).toString());
```

with:

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
Log.d("EXECUTED: " + response );
```

Answer (score 0):

When accessing a URL, a client does normally not need to care the technology that is used behind. This Android app is a client like any other, therefore it does not need to "activate" the PHP script it tries to connect to. The behaviour of this script is up to the server application.